# Pulling a Client ID from a String

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to pull a specific part of a string in PHP using regex.  I just need to get the client ID out, but I am struggling.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 $matches = array();
 $sentance = "Client ID # 050036598BOB BARKER 11/13/2014";
 $clientID = preg_match_all("/Client ID #([0-9]*)[a-zA-Z]/", $str, $matches);
 print_r($clientID);
```

The result I am looking for is

```
  050036598
```

Comment: You need to print `$matches`, not the boolean `preg_match_all()` returns. So what is wrong with yor current code? Except for the missing space between `#` and `(\d*)` it looks fine

Comment: [Aside from a few wrong variable names, such as `$sentance` and you're asking for `$str`, doing a `print_r` on `$clientID` instead of `$matches` and the fact you forgot a space between `#` and `([0-9]*)` it works just fine.](https://eval.in/240872)

Comment: Thank you both.  The variable names were mistakes when I rewrote it for my testing.  The space is what was killing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead and account for whitespace between `#` and the "id".

```
$str = "Client ID # 050036598BOB BARKER 11/13/2014";
preg_match("/# *(\d+)/", $str, $match);
echo $match[1]; //=> "050036598"
```